# Specifications of this Signal Generator

Tags: generator

Can anyone please tell me which is the maximum voltage and current that can be provided by the signal generator [HP 83650B](http://www.testequipmenthq.com/datasheets/Agilent-83650B-Datasheet.pdf) ?

I need that information and don't know where to find it

Comment: If the information is not in the datasheet, ask your supplier or the manufacturer.

Comment: *Always* get the right datasheet for such questions.

Answer (score 4):

On the second page of the data sheet, there's this table

[image]

83650B has a maximum output power (into 50 ohms) of +10dBm below 26.5GHz, +5dBm below 40GHz, and +2.5dBm above 40GHz. Unless you have the attenuator version that is which reduces the power.

So what's +10dBm? 10dB above 1mW, or 10mW. 10mW into a 50 ohm load is an rms voltage of 0.707 volts, or a current of 14.1mA.

If the output is levelled properly, then into an open circuit it will deliver twice this voltage. Into a short circuit, it will deliver twice this current.

For unlevelled operation (ie turned up to the max), you're likely to get an unspecified amount more than these figures, which will vary with frequency.

5dB in linear ratio is 1.778, reduce those voltages and currents by that factor for operation 26.5 to 40GHz.

There is a way to get a little more voltage into loads that have a higher resistance than 50 ohms.You still get the same power. There are two ways of transforming the impedance. The first is to buy an RF transformer, from people like MiniCircuits. The second is to use a quarter wave of intermediate (square root of source*load) impedance transmission line. For instance, if you had a 200 ohm load, a \$(2n+1)\frac{\lambda}{4}\$ length of 100 ohm line would match it at the frequencies for which n was an integer. With four times the load resistance, the voltage into it doubles.

Comment: The 50 ohms that you mention are from the signal generator or the input of the oscilloscope? I hope it's from the signal generator

Comment: Why do you say that 10mW into a 50 ohm load is an rms voltage of 0.707? The calculation gives me 0.0141 V

Comment: `The calculation gives me 0.0141 V` What calculation? The way I do it is this. You know P=IV, and V=IR, so P=V^2/R, or V^2=PR, or V=sqrt(PR). 50 * 0.01 = 0.5. sqrt(0.5) is 0.7071 V rms. That's why I say that 10mW into a 50 ohm load is an rms voltage of 0.707.

Comment: The 50 ohms I mention is the load impedance the power is defined into. It's also the nominal output impedance of the generator, as all RF equipment has controlled impedance inputs and outputs, usually 50ohms, though video equipment tends to use 75 ohms. Most high frequency scopes have switchable 50ohm and 1Mohm impedance. Make sure you know which it's set to when making the measurement.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What you're saying is that at the ouput of the signal generator (using the 50 ohm output of the signal generator) I can have a maximum of 0.707V and 14.1mA. And that's the maximum no matter what's the input of the oscilloscope or the impedance of the cables that I use between the signal generator and the oscilloscope. Is that right?

Comment: No, I said you can have double the voltage into an open circuit (a scope's 1M input is 'open circuit' at a low enough frequency, low enough given there's also usually 30pF in parallel) and double the current into a short circuit. An when you're unlevelled, you might get a bit more, or a lot more.

Comment: Imagine that my circuit is: signal generator (50 ohm output) ---> coaxial1 ---> coaxial 2 ---> channel2, and the coaxial1 is connected to the channel1 of the oscilloscope. Both channels are with 1Mohm and 9pF, for example. Which are the current and voltage there?

Comment: How can coax 1 be connected to ch1 and to coax 2? You'd need to draw a circuit diagram. There are several ways to make that connection and they all have non-trivial effects. You'd also need to specify what frequency you're working at, and the lengths of the cables. BTW, there is a way to get more voltage into non 50 ohm loads, which I've added to my answer.